# How to create this contact section in the footer?

Tags: html

I have a three-column footer and one of the columns need to look like the picture below:

[image]

I think I should use the `<address>` tag in HTML5. Right? But I'm not sure what is the right way to categorize the information.

HTML provides the `dl, dd, and dt` elements but I don't think it's the right way to use those for contact information. I can use an unordered list, but then, again, how I make the "DIRECTOR", "PHONE", "E-mail", and "Main Address" to be bold?

Should I just use a `<h4>` in combination with paragraphs? Something like this:

```
<address>
  <h4>Director</h4>
  <p>Megan Smith</p>
  <h4>Phone:</h4>
  <p>+xxxxxxxx</p>
</address>
```

I have no idea what would be the best way to do it. I would be grateful for any suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how you are comfortable with css. If you wanna completely avoid that and you are fine with the font size the most straight forward way would be.

```
<address>
  <h4>Director</h4>
  <p>Megan Smith</p><br>
  <h4>Phone:</h4>
  <p>+xxxxxxxx</p><br>
</address>
```

Comment: Unfortunately headings are not permitted inside the `<address>` element according to the spec.

Comment: Then replace <h4>Director</h4> to <div style="font-size: 1em; font-weight: bolder">Director</div>
However it may tell you that inline style arent the best way

Answer (score 0):

You can even use `<div>` elements and style them using CSS. You would probably have to use some CSS attributes like `font-weight`, `margin-bottom`, `font-size` etc.

Or if you simply want to make a text bolder, you can enclose them in `<strong>` element